# Evaluate $\int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{(x+\sqrt{1+x^2})^2}$

Tags: calculus, limits, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

How to evaluate this definite integral from MIT Integration Bee 2006?
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{(x+\sqrt{1+x^2})^2}.$$

So far, I have shown that the indefinite integral is

$$\frac{2x^3 + 3x - 2(1+x^2)^{3/2}}{3}.$$

At $x = 0$, the expression above equals $-\dfrac{2}{3}.$

Using WolframAlpha, I also know that the definite integral equals $\dfrac{2}{3}$.

So the only thing left to show is $$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \frac{2x^3 + 3x - 2(1+x^2)^{3/2}}{3}=0.$$

I'm not sure how to calculate this limit.

Comment: The indefinite integral does not seem correct. That seems to be the issue.

Comment: @MathLover I checked three times. I even differentiated. It is correct.

Comment: The indefinite integral is  $-\dfrac{2}{3}(x^2+1)^{\frac{3}{2}}+\dfrac{2}{3}x^3+x+C$. @MathLover , why do you claim that the integral is incorrect?

Comment: @MathLover Yes. The correctness of the definite integral is confirmed by Sathvik Acharaya's comment.

Comment: Differentiate each of the parts one by one. What is the derivative of -$\dfrac{2}{3}(x^2+1)^{\frac{3}{2}}$? $ - 2 x \sqrt{x^2+1}$? Similarly other parts. How do you get from here to a fraction with $x$ terms only in denominator?

Comment: @MathLover, inorder to find the indefinite integral, expand the denominator and then rationalize by multiplying and dividing with $2x\sqrt{x^2+1}-(2x^2+1)$

Comment: @SathvikAcharya take the indefinite integral you have written earlier and differentiate it with respect to $x$. Do you get the integrand? No.

Comment: @MathLover Yes. You get $-2x\sqrt{x^2+1}+2x^2+1$ which is equal to the integrand

Comment: @SathvikAcharya I see what you are saying but I would not rationalize. Here is what the expression comes to after integral: $- \frac{1}{2(x+\sqrt{1+x^2})} - \frac{1}{6(x+\sqrt{1+x^2})^3} $. Definite integral is straightforward $\frac{2}{3}$.

Comment: @user67953840 apologies for confusion. I missed the part that you were rationalizing the integrand and integrating.

Comment: The indefinite integral can be easily evaluated via the substitution $t=x+{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$

Comment: This looks like a Euler substitution question, which will turn it into an easily integrable polynomial function

Comment: Have you seen Taylor series yet? $(1+u)^t=1+tu+O(u^2)$ for $u$ near 0, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is easy to evaluate that definite integral by successive substitutions. I don't see why you evaluate the indefinite one first.

---

\begin{align}\int_0^\infty \frac{\mathrm dx}{(x+\sqrt{1+x^2})^2}&=\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\sec^2 u}{(\tan u+\sec u)^2}\mathrm du \text{ ,via $x=\tan u$}\\&=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\mathrm du}{(\sin u+1)^2}\\&=2\int_0^1 \frac{1+t^2}{(1+t)^4}\mathrm dt\text{ ,via $t=\tan \frac{u}{2}$}\\&=2\int_1^2 \frac{(w-1)^2+1}{w^4}\mathrm dw\text{ ,via $w=t+1$}\\&=2\int_1^2 \left(\frac{1}{w^2}-\frac{2}{w^3}+\frac{2}{w^4}\right)\mathrm dw\\&=\frac{2}{3}\end{align}

**Footnote**

[Weierstrass substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_substitution)

Comment: This is a truly mind-blowing solution. Thanks! Question: To get the third line using Weierstrass substitution will take quite some time, correct? Or is there a mental trick we can do to immediately reach the third line from the second line?

Comment: See the wikipedia link in the footnote. This is a very well known substitution.

Comment: Yes, I understand. I was actually able to do it, but it took me a long time (around two minutes). Is that just the way it is or is there a quick way to do it?

Comment: Yes. If you practice more such questions, you will be able to do much faster.

Answer (score 2):

It's easy to forget about the less common hyperbolic substitutions, but when you do use them you appreciate them even more. Let $x = \sinh t$

$$I = \int_0^\infty \frac{\cosh t \:dt}{(\sinh t + \cosh t)^2} = \int_0^\infty e^{-2t}\left(\frac{e^t+e^{-t}}{2}\right)\:dt = \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{6} = \boxed{\frac{2}{3}}$$

Answer (score 1):

This answer is more for fun than to be taken seriously. I guess you used the conjugate rule trick to calculate the primitive function. Maybe you can use it again to have a simpler expression for the primitive function at the limits?

By the conjugate rule,
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{1}{(\sqrt{1+x^2}+x)^2}
&=
\frac{1}{(\sqrt{1+x^2}+x)^2}\frac{(\sqrt{1+x^2}-x)^2}{(\sqrt{1+x^2}-x)^2}\\
&=
(\sqrt{1+x^2}-x)^2\\
&=
(1+x^2)-2x\sqrt{1+x^2}+x^2,
\end{aligned}
$$
so integrating is easy, and a primitive function is given by
$$
F(x)=x+\frac{2}{3}x^3-\frac{2}{3}(1+x^2)^{3/2}.
$$
From the power $3/2$ of $(1+x^2)$, we look for a term
$$
\begin{aligned}
C(\sqrt{1+x^2}-x)^3&=C(1+x^2)^{3/2}-3Cx(1+x^2)+3Cx^2\sqrt{1+x^2}-Cx^3\\
&=4C(1+x^2)^{3/2}-3Cx(1+x^2)-3C\sqrt{1+x^2}-Cx^3.
\end{aligned}
$$
With $C=-1/6$, we can write our $F$ as
$$
\begin{aligned}
F(x)&=x+\frac{2}{3}x^3-\frac{1}{6}(\sqrt{1+x^2}-x)^3-\frac{1}{2}x(1+x^2)-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{1+x^2}-\frac{1}{6}x^3\\
&=-\frac{1}{6}(\sqrt{1+x^2}-x)^3-\frac{1}{2}(\sqrt{1+x^2}+x)\\
&=-\frac{1}{6}\frac{1}{(\sqrt{1+x^2}+x)^3}-\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}+x}.
\end{aligned}
$$
From this expression it is easy to see that
$$
\lim_{x\to+\infty}F(x)=0.
$$

Comment: Hi, please could you explain what you are doing exactly when you 'look for an expression' etc? I don't understand what you're doing, or why you're doing it. Thanks.

Comment: For the first expression it is not clear (to OP) that it goes to $0$ as $x\to+\infty$. I am looking for a power of $(\sqrt{1+x^2}+x)$ to multiply and divide by, and therefore try to collect the expressions in $F$ as powers of $(\sqrt{1+x^2}-x)$. It is of course a bit silly, but I thought it was also a bit fun.

Comment: Ah, thanks a lot, that's very cool! :)

Answer (score 0):

Let’s tackle the limit by L’Hospital Rule and Rationalization.
$$
\begin{aligned}
& \lim _{x \rightarrow \infty}\left[2 x^{3}+3 x-2\left(1+x^{2}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}\right] \\
=& \lim _{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{2+\frac{3}{x^{2}}-2\left(\frac{1}{x^{2}}+1\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}{\frac{1}{x^{3}}} \quad \left(\frac{0}{0}\right) \\
=& \lim _{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{-\frac{6}{x^{3}}-3 \sqrt{\frac{1}{x^{2}}+1}\left(-\frac{2}{x^{3}}\right)}{-\frac{3}{x^{4}}} \\
=& 2 \lim _{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\left(x-\sqrt{1+x^{2}}\right)\left(x+\sqrt{1+x^{2}}\right)}{x+\sqrt{1+x^{2}}} \\
=&-2 \lim _{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{x+\sqrt{1+x^{2}}} \\
=& 0
\end{aligned}
$$